# Column conflicts with the type of other columns unpivot list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I want execute this procedure, but SQL tell me this error 'The type of column "q82" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list"

al the Q's are INT

Does somebody know solution?

INSERT INTO 
[stg].[fact_answer_cc]

```
        (
        [user_id],
        [question_id],
        [answer],
        [check_sum]
        )
    SELECT 
        [q2] AS [user_id],
        [question_id],
        [answer],
        HASHBYTES (
            N'SHA1',
            ISNULL ( CAST([q2] AS VARCHAR), '' )    + @pipe_delimiter +
            ISNULL ( CAST([question_id] AS VARCHAR), '' )   
            )                                                       AS [check_sum]
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            [q2],
            [q80],
            [q81],
            [q82],
            [q83],
            [q84],
            [q85],
            [q86],
            [q87],
            [q88],
            [q89],
            [q90],
            [q91],
            [q92]
        FROM
            [src].[qa_data_cc]
        ) AS t
    UNPIVOT
        (
        [answer] FOR [question_id] IN 
            (
            [q80],
            [q81],
            [q82],
            [q83],
            [q84],
            [q85],
            [q86],
            [q87],
            [q88],
            [q89],
            [q90],
            [q91],
            [q92]
            )
        ) AS unpvt
    ORDER BY 
        [user_id],
        [question_id];
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of column conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Means your column' s data type same but it' s lenght differ.

Example:

```
q80 VARCHAR(10)
q82 VARCHAR(5)
```

Solution: #Cast all fields to fix value

```
CAST(q80 AS VARCHAR(10))
CAST(q82 AS VARCHAR(10))
```